# Sync error while syncing firebase database with app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I used the firebase tool available in android studio to sync my app with firebase database. After connecting to firebase, I had to add realtime database. Sync failed and the following error showed.:

```
Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0
```

The line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Has red underline and when I hover the mouse over it, it shows all android.support libraries must have same exact version specification.
The sync is failing, although I am using the assistant to add the dependencies Why is it so?

I searched on google where it said to change :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

to :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

But doing so removes the database from the app.The dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had faced the same issue before .If their is the update available then update your android it will fix it.
from my experience when i  use  the assistant to add the dependencies then it comes like this  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'  
 but the it is not correct update it with this
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'  or 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'  or this 
 
maybe this will help you

Comment: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'   : I changed these two to implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0' and now the sync was successful. Thank you!. But the assistant still asks to add implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'  which causes sync error

Comment: add this only `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'` and build it will build successfully